# implement plugable channel to a C# interface

Tags: c#, interface, communication, autofac, channel

Let’s say I have an interface IMyComponent and I want to call it directly or over WCF or some other communication channel how should I deign it?

My idea:

Split this up in a provider and consumer part:

```
IMyComponentProvider: IMyComponent
IMyComponentConsumer: IMyComponent
```

And build a object that wires this two interfaces together:

MyComponent (MyComponentProvider) <- Channel( MyComponentConsumer) <- calling context

Questions:

- What are the alternatives especially with autofac?
- Which design pattern applies to this and the alternatives?
- Which naming conventions are useful or standard?

Comment: Maybe this is "chain of responsibility"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no generalized solution for this problem. It is not really a "chain of responsibility", because you don't want to give any participant the chance to handle this request.
But it can loosely be seen as a "chain of filters".

The problem with Autofac is that you have register your components and build the Autofac container before you can use it. It is not possible to resolve a component and register a replacement later.

If you know your chain, you can register special interfaces for it:
Register( IComponent, ComponentType )
Register(IComponentChannel, ComponentChannelType) this is like your provider / consumer pattern.

Alternatively you must decorate your component with the channel and register the decorated interface.
Register( IComponent, ChannelDecorator) )